# Execution failed for task app:processDebugResources. Android resource linking failed

Tags: android

Please help me to solve this error in Android Studio.

Three errors pop up:

1. Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values/values.xml:3854: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:23: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> error: failed linking references.
> 2) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values/values.xml:3854: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:23: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> error: failed linking references.
> 3) Android resource linking failed
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values/values.xml:3854: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> art.dorozhkinsa.app-mergeDebugResources-17:/values-night-v8/values-night-v8.xml:23: error: expected reference but got (raw string) null.
> error: failed linking references.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YumiZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP6OI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBB4X.png)

Comment: Could you also include your `values-night-v8.xml` in your question?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyH6X.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtiwi.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGJd6.png

Comment: Updated in the implementation version lines in the Build Gradle file, the lines are not shown in red, there is a green checkmark. But the error still persists.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo5jt.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLvnN.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your night theme has an invalid value for `android:windowContentOverlay`.

Replace with `@null` instead of `null`.

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: Replaced with @null. However, another error popped up - Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J82G3.png

Comment: Thank you. So far, this error seems to have stopped popping up.